# Cannot access html Response

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use [The Cat API](http://thecatapi.com/docs.html) to get a random pic of a cat.
when I run the following code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('test');
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://thecatapi.com/api/images/get",
    type: "GET",
    data: {
      "format": "html"
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('test1');
      console.log(data);
      console.log('test2')
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The success event never fires but I can see a response in Network log that looks like this.

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://thecatapi.com/?id=crt"><img src="http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m0j1osiek21qewacoo1_500.jpg"></a>
```

How do I gain access to that response ?

Comment: What do you see in the console?

Comment: just the first test

Comment: but that gives me a raw image and not a url to the image which is what i want

Answer (score 1):

If you add quotes around the data then you will get the information you're looking for.  Also, I added an `error` step because your original code was sending an error and that will help find issues.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('test');
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://thecatapi.com/api/images/get",
    type: "GET",
    data: "{'format': 'html'}",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('test1');
      console.log(data);
      console.log('test2')
    },
    error: function(data){
       console.log('error');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also, you could use the `JSON.stringify` method:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('test');
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://thecatapi.com/api/images/get",
    type: "GET",
    data: JSON.stringify({format: 'html'}),
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('test1');
      console.log(data);
      console.log('test2')
    },
    error: function(data){
       console.log('error');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Eric, this still returns a raw image rather than the image url. is there a way we can get the image url

Comment: ok your error code helped me figure out how to access the data i want, thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://thecatapi.com/api/images/get",
  type: "GET",
  data:{
    format: 'html',
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(data){
    console.log('error');
  }
});
```

This is how it would be done in my opinion. But it gives you an error.
If you open the url in the browser you'll also get an error.
https://thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=html

if you change the format to `xml` it works. I guess its an issue of the cat api with the `html` format.

Comment: yes and now that i see i can access what i need in the error that works for me

Comment: yeah but the xml doesn't have the image url ending in .jpg .png .gi

Comment: The xml response contains the url. You could get it out of the response. But I know that's not what you wanted :) I just said that to show you, that it is the cat api which does not handle the `html` format correctly and not the code.